# Asus ROG Flow X16 Sleeping When Not Intended

Tags: sleep, asus-laptop, overheating, poweroff, armoury-crate

I recently got the Asus ROG Flow X16 with the Ryzen 9 6900hs. For my use cases, there have immediately been some strange issues.

1. Computer puts itself to sleep immediately when lid is closed, regardless of windows "Change what happens when you close the lid" settings. I was able to partially solve this if I use the "Windows" performance profile inside the included Armoury Crate software. However, if I want to swap to "Turbo" profile for boosted performance, the laptop will go to sleep if the lid is closed. This is a problem as I use the laptop docked and attached to an external monitor and cannot leave the lid open. I have changed ALL available Windows settings related to sleep: Power Options > Edit Power Plan, Windows 11 settings, etc.
2. When in the "Windows" performance setting through Armoury Crate, the laptop will still occasionally put itself to sleep when under a heavy load. With the CPU maxed out I was seeing CPU temps of about 85c. Thermal limit on this chip should be about 95c, so I shouldn't even see throttling at this level much less thermal protection. I am not sure if this sleeping is a falsely triggered thermal protection or something else?

These issues are making it a pain to work with this laptop unfortunately. I could try uninstalling the Asus Armoury Crate software, but then I would lose access to the MUX switch capability I believe. Or, perhaps there is a way to change this in the Windows Power Plans instead? Armoury Crate also allows modification of the keyboard RGB but that isn't a deal breaker.

Any ideas of how to remedy this unintended sleep issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who have this problem (or other problems) with Asus laptops and Armoury Crate:

There is an open-source replacement for Armoury Crate called G-Helper: https://github.com/seerge/g-helper

I installed G-Helper, uninstalled Armoury Crate, and now I can switch between power profiles without my laptop sleeping itself with the lid closed. Note that I also did set all power profiles in windows to not sleep when lid is closed.

Even better, G-Helper allows me to use the Fn lock which is missing from Armoury Crate.

I have not highly stressed the system again in a bit so not sure if the sleeping-under-load issue is fixed, but will test in the future.